# adding click event to class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found found several question's answers similar to this, I tried some of them, but no luck. May my scenario is different, I want to make other checkbox disable when anyone of them is clicked. if one is clicked second go disabled.

Edit:

I have two checkboxes i.e; `chk1` and `chk2`. if chk1 is checked `chk2` become disable, if `chk2` is checked chk1 become disable

**HTML**

```
<tr class="cart-item-row">
<td class="remove-from-cart">
<label class="td-title">Remove:</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="removefromcart" value="4392" tabindex="15" class="class2">
</td>
<td class="add-to-cart">
<label class="td-title">Buy Now:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="addtocart" value="4392" tabindex="16" class="class2">
</td>                                                                                                                      

 </tr>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(function () { // I am also adding class to checkbox through JS
        $('.cart-item-row > td > input[type="checkbox"]').addClass("class2");
    });
</script>
<script>
    //$('input[class^="class"]').click(function () {
 //$('.class2').unbind().click(function () {
    $('.class2').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.is(".class2")) {
            if ($this.is(":checked")) {
                $(".class2").not($this).prop({ disabled: true, checked: false });

            } else {
                $(".class2").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a radio input type instead of a checkbox, that way it's default browser behaviour :)

Comment: @jedifans but I want to perform this with checkboxes

Comment: can you please re write the requirement. The code you wrote is different from the problem description

Comment: @qadeer but why? Do you have more than two options?

Comment: @user2181397 edited

Comment: no only two @jedifans

Comment: @Qadeer what will happen if one is unchecked?

Comment: @user2181397 I got the solution in answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missing , You can place your jquery within

$(document).ready(function(){
}

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your click event in document ready state `$(function () { });`

You can see here working [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1bgbfdhL/11/)